# How to limit results display on a page from foreach func and break it to several pages

Tags: php

I have a code that fetches and displays results using foreach function but problem is it returns a lot of results so page loading is very slow! Is there any way to break these results into pages like 1,2,3,4 & display only 10 results per page?

my code is

```
foreach ($results[1] as $url)
{
    echo "<a href='$url'>$url</a> <br>";

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: If the data is coming from a database, you should limit it there already with a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: Google a php pagination tutorial.

Comment: I would definitely look into `LIMIT` as @jeroen said.

Comment: You have to limit it on your query and then just display the page number, items, limit and offset values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is coming from a database, you should limit it there already with a `LIMIT` clause.

If you have no control over the source of the data, you can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) on `$results[1]` to get the section you want, based on the page-number and the number of items you want to display:

```
$partial_results = array_slice($results[1], ($page_number - 1) * $items_to_show, $items_to_show);
```

Answer (score 1):

This **PHP CLASS** might Help: http://www.phpsnaps.com/snaps/view/simple-php-pagination-class/